Point-Set Topology of Diagrams of Spaces
There is an extensive literature on the homotopy theory of diagrams of spaces (i.e. on functors of the form $\mathcal{D}\to\mathbf{Top}$, from a fixed category $\mathcal{D}$, to the category of topological spaces or its subcategory).
Has anything been written on the point-set topology of these objects? (e.g. When $\mathcal{D}$ is discrete it should be equivalent to the topology of the product)

"When $\mathcal{D}$ is discrete it should be equivalent to the topology of the product" I don't understand what this is supposed to mean. A functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathrm{Top}$ in this case is the same thing as a collection of spaces indexed by the objects of $\mathcal{D}$. How is this supposed to carry a topology?
